# Convert GMT time to local time

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

Am getting a GMT time from my server in this format

```
Fri, 18 Oct 2013 11:38:23 GMT
```

My requirement is to convert this time to local time using Javascript, eg:/  if the user is from India, first i need to take the time zone +5.30 and add that to my servertime and convert the time string to the following format

```
2013-10-18 16:37:06
```

I tried with following code but not working

```
var date = new Date('Fri, 18 Oct 2013 11:38:23 GMT');
date.toString();
```

Please help me to solve this issue, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<script>
var strDateTime = "Fri, 18 Oct 2013 11:38:23 GMT";
var myDate = new Date(strDateTime);
alert(myDate.toLocaleString());
</script>
```

Please take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp for all further date time manipulations, from the date object myDate.

Comment: Yes, now its working, thank you so much for your help, Do you have any idea about convert this date fromat 18/10/2013 17:08:23" in to 2013-10-18 17:08:23

Comment: Hope you dont mind asking a doubt, is this conversion based on users system time/browser time ? What will happened when their time zone are wrong in their system. Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: Yes it's browser's time, so Windows Locale Settings or any OS, We should not care about the wrong browser settings - let him a wrong info. Sorry.

Comment: Why do you have to put the day and date, is there a way to do it with just the time?