# convert a date into Indian Standard Time format

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, datetime

Technology used: Nodejs, mongo DB, AWS server.

I've been trying to achieve this since morning but no success 
by following some of the references from here and there like [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491222/convert-gmt-time-to-local-time), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990367/converting-a-date-string-into-utc0530-format-using-javascript), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517024/how-to-assume-local-time-zone-when-parsing-iso-8601-date-string) and this one

```js
var sDate = "2016-02-16T09:22:25.881Z";
var sourceDate = new Date(sDate);
alert(sourceDate);
```

in the case of basic js this snippet works as I want but in the case of node js this is not converted and returns the value as it is. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try [Moment-Timezone.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/). It is specifically to deal with the Time issues in javascript.